Why 論文に鞭うたれた is in passive form?
From Kokoro chapter 25:

それでも私は馬車馬のように正面ばかり見て、論文に鞭うたれた。

I am bit uncertain why 鞭打つ is written in passive form here. I wonder if this question is related here.

鞭打つ is a rather simple transitive verb meaning "to whip (and drive) someone", and the sentence is a plain passive sentence using this verb. The sentence means "I was whipped by the dissertation" or "I was driven by (the pressure of) the dissertation".
The linked question is not relevant (軍服を着る makes sense but 論文を鞭打つ doesn't).

Thanks. How do you say say "work oneself to complete a dissertation"? If 論文を鞭打つ sounds wrong, then maybe 体に鞭打って論文を書き上げる will work?

@weeab00 Yes, that sounds perfect. 体を鞭打って also works.
